# get cpu utilization of Database in azure using python sdk

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, azure-sdk-python

Below is the code for azure vm CPU utilization like to get whether my VM is idle or not want to do the same for Azure database could you guys suggest me something...

```
import datetime
from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient

# Get the ARM id of your resource. You might chose to do a "get"
# using the according management or to build the URL directly
# Example for a ARM VM
resource_id = (
    "subscriptions/{}/"
    "resourceGroups/{}/"
    "providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{}"
).format(subscription_id, resource_group_name, vm_name)

# create client
client = MonitorManagementClient(
    credentials,
    subscription_id
)

# You can get the available metrics of this specific resource
for metric in client.metric_definitions.list(resource_id):
    # azure.monitor.models.MetricDefinition
    print("{}: id={}, unit={}".format(
        metric.name.localized_value,
        metric.name.value,
        metric.unit
    ))

# Example of result for a VM:
# Percentage CPU: id=Percentage CPU, unit=Unit.percent
# Network In: id=Network In, unit=Unit.bytes
# Network Out: id=Network Out, unit=Unit.bytes
# Disk Read Bytes: id=Disk Read Bytes, unit=Unit.bytes
# Disk Write Bytes: id=Disk Write Bytes, unit=Unit.bytes
# Disk Read Operations/Sec: id=Disk Read Operations/Sec, unit=Unit.count_per_second
# Disk Write Operations/Sec: id=Disk Write Operations/Sec, unit=Unit.count_per_second

# Get CPU total of yesterday for this VM, by hour

today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

metrics_data = client.metrics.list(
    resource_id,
    timespan="{}/{}".format(yesterday, today),
    interval='PT1H',
    metric='Percentage CPU',
    aggregation='Total'
)

for item in metrics_data.value:
    # azure.mgmt.monitor.models.Metric
    print("{} ({})".format(item.name.localized_value, item.unit.name))
    for timeserie in item.timeseries:
        for data in timeserie.data:
            # azure.mgmt.monitor.models.MetricData
            print("{}: {}".format(data.time_stamp, data.total))

# Example of result:
# Percentage CPU (percent)
# 2016-11-16 00:00:00+00:00: 72.0
# 2016-11-16 01:00:00+00:00: 90.59
# 2016-11-16 02:00:00+00:00: 60.58
# 2016-11-16 03:00:00+00:00: 65.78
# 2016-11-16 04:00:00+00:00: 43.96
# 2016-11-16 05:00:00+00:00: 43.96
# 2016-11-16 06:00:00+00:00: 114.9
# 2016-11-16 07:00:00+00:00: 45.4
```

So in a similar way I need to find whether my azure database is idle or not if idle then I will stop it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no python sdk to get the metrics of CPU used by azure database.

Alternatively, we can get those details including the percentage of available CPU used by your database by using the azure portal i.e., Goto-->Azure Sql Database in portal--> select **Query Performance Insight**--> under **Intelligent Performance** tab as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

Here we can see the CPU usage will displayed as a percentage of total available CPU used for the database and also, we can see the SQL queries which are consuming the high CPU as shown below:

[image]